# Proof involving unfolding two recursive functions in COQ

Tags: coq, proof, coq-tactic

I've began learning Coq, and am trying to prove something that seems fairly simple: if a list contains x, then the number of instances of x in that list will be > 0.

I've defined the contains and count functions as follows:

```
Fixpoint contains (n: nat) (l: list nat) : Prop :=
  match l with
  | nil => False
  | h :: t => if beq_nat h n then True else contains n t
  end.

Fixpoint count (n acc: nat) (l: list nat) : nat :=
  match l with
  | nil => acc
  | h :: t => if beq_nat h n then count n (acc + 1) t else count n acc t
  end.
```

I'm trying to prove:

```
Lemma contains_count_ge1 : forall (n: nat) (l: list nat), contains n l -> (count n 0 l > 0).
```

I understand the proof will involve unfolding the definitions of count and contains, but then I'd like to say "the list cannot be nil, as contains is true, so there must be an element `x` in `l` such that `beq_nat h x` is true", and I've played around a bit but can't figure out how to use tactics to do this. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you pose many questions about basic Coq beyond what is IMO possible to address here. For this particular problem, I would proceed this way (in reality I would use the already provided lemmas in MathComp):

```
From Coq Require Import PeanoNat Bool List.

Fixpoint contains (n: nat) (l: list nat) : bool :=
  match l with
  | nil    => false
  | h :: t => if Nat.eqb h n then true else contains n t
  end.

Fixpoint count (n : nat) (l: list nat) : nat :=
  match l with
  | nil => 0
  | h :: t => if Nat.eqb h n then S (count n t) else count n t
  end.

Lemma contains_count_ge1 n l : contains n l = true -> count n l > 0.
Proof.
induction l as [|x l IHl]; simpl; [now congruence|].
now destruct (Nat.eqb_spec x n); auto with arith.
Qed.
```

My "standard" solution:

```
Lemma test n (l : list nat) : n \in l -> 0 < count_mem n l.
Proof. by rewrite lt0n => /count_memPn/eqP. Qed.
```

and different definitions of `count` and `contains` that may prove useful:

```
Fixpoint contains (n: nat) (l: list nat) : bool :=
  match l with
  | nil    => false
  | h :: t => Nat.eqb h n || contains n t
  end.

Fixpoint count (n : nat) (l: list nat) : nat :=
  match l with
  | nil    => 0
  | h :: t => Nat.b2n (Nat.eqb h n) + (count n t)
  end.
```

Answer (score 6):

ejgallego already gave a great solution to your problem in his answer.  I would still like to single out an important point that he left out: in Coq, you must always argue from first principles, and be very pedantic and precise about your proofs.

You argued that the proof should proceed as follows:

> The list cannot be `nil`, as `contains` is true, so there must be an element `x` in `l` such that `beq_nat h x` is `true`.

Even though this makes intuitive sense for humans, it is not precise enough for Coq to understand.  The problem, as ejgallego's answer shows, is that your informal reasoning conceals a use of induction.  Indeed, it is useful to try to expand out your argument in more details even before translating it into tactics.  We could proceed like this, for instance:

Let us prove that, for every `n : nat` and `ns : list nat`, `contains n ns` implies `count n 0 ns > 0`. We proceed by induction on the list `ns`.  If `ns = nil`, the definition of `contains` implies that `False` holds; a contradiction. We are thus left with the case `ns = n' :: ns'`, where we can use the following induction hypothesis: `contains n ns' -> count n 0 ns' > 0`. There are two sub-cases to consider: whether `beq_nat n n'` is `true` or not.

- If `beq_nat n n'` is `true`, by the definition of `count`, we see that we just have to show that `count n (0 + 1) ns' > 0`.  Note there isn't a direct way to proceed here. This is because you wrote `count` tail-recursively, using an accumulator.  While this is perfectly reasonable in functional programming, it can making proving properties about `count` more difficult.  In this case, we would need the following auxiliary lemma, also proved by induction: `forall n acc ns, count n acc ns = acc + count n 0 ns`.  I'll let you figure out how to prove this one.  But assuming that we have already established it, the goal would reduce to showing that `1 + count n 0 ns' > 0`. This is true by simple arithmetic.  (There is an even simpler way that does not require an auxiliary lemma, but it would require slightly generalizing the statement you're proving.)
- If `beq_nat n n'` is `false`, by the definitions of `contains` and `count`, we would need to show that `contains n ns'` implies `count n 0 ns' > 0`. This is exactly what the induction hypothesis gives us, and we are done.

There are two lessons to be learned here.  The first one is that doing formal proofs often requires translating your intuition in formal terms that the system can understand.  We know intuitively what it means to have some element occur inside of a list.  But if we were to explain what that means more formally, we would resort to some kind of recursive traversal of the list, which would probably turn out to be the very definition of `count` that you wrote in Coq. And in order to reason about recursion, we need induction.  The second lesson is that the way you define things in Coq has important consequences for the proofs you write.  ejgallego's solution did not require any auxiliary lemmas beyond those in the standard library, precisely because his definition of `count` was not tail-recursive.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive explanation! I'm not sure which answer I should tick here, as while yours explains in more detail the approach I should take, the other answer provides an example in code of how to do it in Coq; both answers are quite helpful.

Comment: Either works for me; @ejgallego did put up a very nice solution.